# How use JQuery closest() in Post and comment system

Tags: php, jquery

I have a post and comment system. Something like facebook post and comment system. The post display properly but the comments only display for the first post i.e the post displayed at the top. Am on able to submit comment on all other posts except the first post.
The problem on which I need your assistance is as follows:
-The comments for each of the posts should display correspondently.
-To be able to submit comments for the other posts.

These what I have done.
View:

```
                <div class="box-footer" style="display: block;">
                    <form id="com" class="com" method="post">
                    <div class="img-push">
                        <input type="hidden"  class="status_id" id="status_id" name="status_id" value="<?php echo $post['spid']; ?>">

                        <textarea  name="comment" id="comment" class="form-control input-sm comment" placeholder="Press enter to post comment"></textarea>

                         <div class="box-footer box-form">
                          <btn class="btn btn-azure btn-sm pull-right commentbt" id="commentbt">Comment</btn>
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                        <li><i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                    </div>
              <?php endforeach;?>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".commentbt").click(function(){
        var comment = $(this).closest("div.img-push").find("input[name='comment']").val();
        alert(comment);

    });
});
```

All am getting is "Undefined"
I need to get the value of the input field and the textarea. Thanks

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think you need to quotation marks arount `'comment'`.

Comment: I removed the quotation but still didn't work

Comment: And if you change `.commentbt` to `#commentbt`?

Comment: #commentbt only work for the first post comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can notice, initially, the next errors on your code:

**1)** You forgot the close `div` for `<div class="box-footer" style="display:block;">`

**2)** The attribute `name` of the input element is `status_id`, not `comment`

**3)** The usage of the same `ID` attribute for multiple elements.

**4)** On JQuery, I will replace the search of the input by matching by class. Also, I added the search of textarea value too.

So, try next modifications:

**PHP**

```
<?php foreach ($statuspost as $post): ?>
  <div class="box-footer" style="display:block;">
    <form class="com" method="post">
      <div class="img-push">

        <input type="hidden" class="status_id" name="status_id" value="<?php echo $post['spid'];?>">

        <textarea name="comment" class="form-control input-sm comment" placeholder="Press enter to post comment"></textarea>

        <div class="box-footer box-form">
          <btn class="btn btn-azure btn-sm pull-right commentbt">Comment</btn>
          <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li><i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
<?php endforeach:?>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".commentbt").click(function()
    {
        var statusID = $(this).closest("div.img-push").find("input.status_id").val();
        alert(statusID);
        var comment = $(this).closest("div.img-push").find("textarea.comment").val();
        alert(comment);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, thanks it worked now. And also submit the comments successfully. Also, i need the comment to display for all the post.

Comment: Can you explain better your current issue now? I have also updated with the removal of all the `ID` attribute of all the `tags`, since it is not a good practice using the same `ID` for multiple elements.

Comment: I have the part of the Jquery that displays the comments immediately, but only works for the first post alone, the other comments for the other posts are not showing.

Comment: You should open a new question then, showing the code (or the relevant part of it) that have that issue. On this question I can only see the html markup construction, and a listener on a click event for comments buttons.

Comment: @SholleyonlineJava, you should not do that, since now my answer don't match with your first question and all will be inconsistent, and probably generate down votes on my answer, you should have made a new question. Anyway, I will check it when i have some time.

Comment: Thanks, it will be appreciated. Just put the link of your new question here when you have made it, and I will check it later.

Comment: Kindly check this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53216982/displaying-comments-for-all-post