# How to display comments for all post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a post and comment system. Something like facebook post and comment system. The post display properly, I can submit comment on all posts. But the comments only display for the first post i.e the post displayed at the top.  .
The problem on which I need your assistance is as follows:
-The comments for each of the posts should display correspondently.

These what I have done.
View:

```
  <div class="box box-widget">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                  <div class="user-block">

                    <span class="description">Shared publicly - <?php echo time_ago($post['post_date'])?></span>

                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="box-body" style="display: block;">
                  <img class="img-responsive show-in-modal" src="<?php echo base_url('post_file/'.$post['post_image'])?>" alt="">
                  <input type="hidden" id="stid" value="<?php echo $post['spid']; ?>">
                  <p><?php echo $post['postcontent']?></p>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> Share</button>
                  <div>

                  <input type="hidden" id="pl_postid" name="pl_postid" value="<?php echo $post['spid']; ?>">

                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> Like</button>
                 </div>
                  <span class="pull-right text-muted"><?php //echo $countlikes ?> likes - 3 comments</span>

                </div>
                  <div id="display_comment"></div>
                <div class="box-footer" style="display: block;">
                    <form id="com" class="com" method="post">
                    <div class="img-push">
                        <input type="hidden"  class="status_id" id="status_id" name="status_id" value="<?php echo $post['spid']; ?>">

                        <textarea  name="comment" id="comment" class="form-control input-sm comment" placeholder="Press enter to post comment"></textarea>

                         <div class="box-footer box-form">
                          <btn class="btn btn-azure btn-sm pull-right commentbt" id="commentbt">Comment</btn>
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                        <li><i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                    </div>

              </div>
              <?php endforeach;?>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".commentbt").click(function(){
        var status_id = $(this).closest("div.img-push").find("input[name='status_id']").val();
        var comment = $(this).closest("div.img-push").find("textarea[name='comment']").val();
        alert(comment);

        var dataString = 'status_id='+ status_id +'&comment='+ comment;
        if(comment==''||status_id==''){
            alert('Can not send empty comment')
        }
        else{
            $('#display_comment').show();
            //$("#display_comment").fadeIn(100).html('<img src="<?php //echo base_url();?>uploads/ajax-loader.gif" />Loading Comment...');
            $.ajax({
               type:"POST",
               url:"<?php echo site_url('user/postcomment')?>",
               data:dataString,
               cache:false,
             success: function () {
         $(document).ready(function(){
        var status_id = $("#stid").val();
        $.post('<?php echo site_url('user/getcomments');?>',
        {
            status_id:status_id
        },
        function(data){
            $("#display_comment").html(data);
        });
    });


                    $('#com')[0].reset();
                }
            });
        }return false;
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is the loop for the comments, generally one would need a loop to output the results from the database.  Than again where are those... Are you sure you pulling the data from the DB in the first place etc...

Comment: Yes, I did with foreach, the comments are sent to a comment page from which I use Jquery to display

Comment: So, the first `ajax` call to this `<?php echo site_url('user/postcomment')?>` is working fine, but the next one: `$.post('<?php echo site_url('user/getcomments');?>'` that should get the submited comment is not working fine? You say this one is displaying comments on the top one post?

Comment: $.post('<?php echo site_url('user/getcomments');?>' is working but only displays comment for the post at the top ignoring other post below.

Comment: @SholleyonlineJava Do my answer help you? Please check it when you have some time.

Comment: @D.Smania      Have checked it but still not working as expected. The comments now displays on all the post but the comments displayed are those of the top post.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML Fixes:**

Don't use the same `ID` on differents elements, like you are doing with `display_comment`. You are creating a set of posts with the foreach loop, so this will create multiple elements with the same `ID`. Use a custom class instead. **Remenber** there should not be more than one item with the same `ID`. The elements that where fixed are next ones:

`<input type="hidden" id="stid" value="<?php echo $post['spid'];?>">`

`<input type="hidden" id="pl_postid" name="pl_postid" value="<?php echo $post['spid']; ?>">`

`<div id="display_comment"></div>`

`<form id="com" class="com" method="post">`

`<input type="hidden" class="status_id" id="status_id" name="status_id" value="<?php echo $post['spid'];?>">`

`<textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="form-control input-sm comment" placeholder="Press enter to post comment"></textarea>`

`<btn class="btn btn-azure btn-sm pull-right commentbt" id="commentbt">Comment</btn>`

Since you are creating multiples `box-widget`, the previous elements will generate multiple of they with the same `ID`. The fixed code will be like this:

```
<div class="box box-widget">

  <div class="box-header with-border">
    <div class="user-block">
      <span class="description">Shared publicly - <?php echo time_ago($post['post_date'])?></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box-body" style="display:block;">
    <img class="img-responsive show-in-modal" src="<?php echo base_url('post_file/'.$post['post_image'])?>" alt="">
    <input type="hidden" class="stid" value="<?php echo $post['spid'];?>">
    <p><?php echo $post['postcontent']?></p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
      <i class="fa fa-share"></i> Share
    </button>
    <div>
      <input type="hidden" class="pl_postid" name="pl_postid" value="<?php echo $post['spid']; ?>">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> Like
      </button>
    </div>
    <span class="pull-right text-muted"><?php //echo $countlikes ?> likes - 3 comments</span>
  </div>

  <div class="display_comment"></div>

  <div class="box-footer" style="display:block;">
    <form class="com" method="post">
      <div class="img-push">
        <input type="hidden" class="status_id" name="status_id" value="<?php echo $post['spid'];?>">
        <textarea name="comment" class="form-control input-sm comment" placeholder="Press enter to post comment"></textarea>

        <div class="box-footer box-form">
          <btn class="btn btn-azure btn-sm pull-right commentbt">Comment</btn>
          <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li><i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

**JQUERY Fixes:**

**1)** The main problem on this section is that you was targeting the elements by `ID`, and you had multiple elements with the same `ID`, so you probably was targeting only the first element with those `ID` that appears on the HTML. So, how to proceed? Try to find elements by the relation they have with the clicked button, like the approach you use for:

`var status_id = $(this).closest("div.img-push").find("input[name='status_id']").val();`

**2)** Another issue was using the `$(document).ready()` inside the ajax call, that was removed.

A fixed code should look like this:

```
$(".commentbt").click(function()
{
    var status_id = $(this).closest("div.img-push").find("input[name='status_id']").val();
    var comment = $(this).closest("div.img-push").find("textarea[name='comment']").val();

    alert(comment);

    var dataString = 'status_id=' + status_id + ' &comment=' + comment;

    if (comment == '' || status_id == '')
    {
        alert('Can not send empty comment')

        // Finish function here if error detected!
        return;
    }

    // The next line was fixed!
    //$('#display_comment').show();
    var dComment = $(this).closest(".box-widget").find(".display_comment");
    dComment.show();

    // The next line was also wrong (Homework for you...)
    //$("#display_comment").fadeIn(100).html('<img src="<?php //echo base_url();?>uploads/ajax-loader.gif" />Loading Comment...');

    // Save clicked button object, we going to need it inside the ajax.
    var clickedBtn = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo site_url('user/postcomment')?>",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function()
        {
            // Wrong again, the next line was fixed!!
            //var status_id = $("#stid").val();
            var status_id = clickedBtn.closest(".box-widget").find("input.stid").val();

            console.log("Getting comments for status_id = " + status_id);

            $.post(
                "<?php echo site_url('user/getcomments');?>",
                {status_id: status_id},
                function(data)
                {
                   // Wrong again! Fixed!
                   //$("#display_comment").html(data);
                   dComment.html(data);
                }
            );

            // Another error, guess what...
            //$('#com')[0].reset();
            clickedBtn.closest("form.com").reset();
        }
    });
});
```

> Finally, i have to said, i really doubt your code will still work at
>   all after all the changes i have made, but i hope at least you
>   understood the mains issues you was committing.

Comment: I applied all the identified changes. Still not working as expected but displays comments on all the post. The comments displayed are those for the top post.

Comment: Just fixed this line: `var status_id = clickedBtn.closest(".box-widget").find("input.stid");` to this `var status_id = clickedBtn.closest(".box-widget").find("input.stid").val();`. Also, check that this `<?php echo $post['spid']; ?>` is different for each **.box.widget** element.